# Create reusable matAutocomplete directive

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to implement a component or directive to use with the Angular Material [autocomplete component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview). However I am having difficulty figuring out how to encapsulate the business logic and wire it up while still exposing the input element so it is easy to style and add accessibility.

Ideally I would like to have a directive I can just add to the input but my understanding is that you need to instantiate the `<mat-autocomplete>` component. Therefore I've tried to create a component to instantiate the `<mat-option>` list.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'employee-search',
  exportAs: 'employeeSearch',
  template: `
    <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees | async" [value]="employee.globalId">
      <span>
        <span>{{ employee.name }}</span> |
        <small>{{ employee.globalId }}</small>
      </span>
    </mat-option>
  `,
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  control = new FormControl();
  employees: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private rest: MyRestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = this.control.valueChanges
    .filter((value: string) => value && value.length >= 3)
    .debounceTime(300)
    switchMap((value: string) => this.loadEmployees(value));
  }

  loadEmployees(searchInput: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.rest.get('/employees', { filter: searchInput });
  }
}
```

I've tried to use this component within the `<mat-autocomplete>` component and it does seem to be making the http call to load the data but the options are not loading.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Employee" aria-label="Employee"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [formControl]="employee.control">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <employee-search #employee="employeeSearch"></employee-search>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

How can I create a component or directive to make an input show my custom autocomplete list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I implemented this by wrapping the `<mat-autocomplete>` and passing it through to the input.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'employee-search',
  exportAs: 'employeeSearch',
  template: `
    <mat-autocomplete>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees | async" [value]="employee.globalId">
        <span>
          <span>{{ employee.name }}</span> |
          <small>{{ employee.globalId }}</small>
        </span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  `,
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  control = new FormControl();
  employees: Observable<any[]>;

  @ViewChild(MatAutocomplete) autocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor(private rest: MyRestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employees = this.control.valueChanges
    .filter((value: string) => value && value.length >= 3)
    .debounceTime(300)
    switchMap((value: string) => this.loadEmployees(value));
  }

  loadEmployees(searchInput: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.rest.get('/employees', { filter: searchInput });
  }
}
```

Then using a template ref variable I was able to access the control and autocomplete properties.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Employee" aria-label="Employee"
      [matAutocomplete]="employee.autocomplete"
      [formControl]="employee.control">
</mat-form-field>
<employee-search #employee="employeeSearch"></employee-search>
```

Comment: In putting in place this solution, it seemed sufficient to use `#employee`, thus avoiding the mysterious `exportAs` field.